# Star rating inside a kendo grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid, kendo-template

So first off, I am only recently diving into the world of jquery and kendo, having spent the last few years with webforms (and I really need to get this working or else it's back to the webforms gulag) so bear with me if this is a stupid question.

I have a functional kendo grid on a web page, but I need to allow users to assign a star rating to the contents of each row.  Unfortunately, kendo does not provide a star rating control, but I have been able to find several third party controls.

I found one that appears to work, but I'm not sure how to get it to work inside the grid.  The best I have been able to do is to define a template that contains the star rating control and to use that as the contents of the grid column.  Then I put the initialization ( $("#stars").rateYo({rating:5}); ) inside the "complete" callback of the datasource.  Unfortunately only the first row ends up with an initialized widget.

What do I need to do to get my jquery widget to render on EACH grid row?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Kendo Grid in MVC, here is the codes I am using:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<YourDataModel>().Columns(columns =>
{ 
  columns.Bound(c => 
  c.Rating).Title("Rating").ClientTemplate("#= 
  myStarTemplate(data) #"));
  //columns.Bound for more fields....
})
)
```